# Is Codenameone geofencing locations limited to 1?

Tags: java, codenameone, geofencing

I'm trying geofence some locations and only one is firing up. This makes me want to ask how many locations can be geofenced in a single app? So that when I reach those locations, my app triggers the events.

Below is how I'm setting up the geofencing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
    Location loc = new Location();
    loc.setLatitude(aLatitude);
    loc.setLongitude(aLongitude);
    int radius = myRadius;
    Geofence gf = new Geofence(aUniqueIdString, loc, radius, 100000000);
    LocationManager.getLocationManager().addGeoFencing(GeofenceListenerImpl.class, gf);
}
```

Comment: On which platform? Android?

Comment: I've only tried it on iOS platform

Comment: It should work with multiple locations but I'll ping Steve for a confirmation

Comment: Ios should allow up to 20 Geofences at a time.

Comment: @stevehannah What happens to new locations added when the 20 has been reached? Let's say I'm adding 100 locations.

Comment: @Diamond Currently there is no feedback if geofence fails.  I have just posted an RFE to add the ability to get the registered geofence IDs which would give you a mechanism to verify that it worked.  https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1799

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no limit as to how many geofences that could be created.

I tested with 100 places on devices and checked the 100th location to see if its set, yes it was set.